# Integrating Javadoc for Java EE 6 API into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, jboss7.x

I'm using the new JBoss 7.1 which implements the full Java EE 6 standard and Eclipse Indigo.

Is it possible to get all the Javadoc for the EE Api working in Eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

While the above solution does work, I am personally looking for a smoother solution.

So far I've gathered that for each jboss jar under the build path, I can reference the following url (or as Tiberiu stated, the location where you downloaded the docs):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

This works fine. But there are approximately 10-15 libraries referenced in a given java ee project. Adding the above url to each library, **for every new java ee project** seems ridiculous to me.

I should think there is a way to specify where "the javadoc for the entire jboss 7 runtime" is located, not just for the individual libraries. Currently I'm still searching, but if anyone knows how to do this please enlighten me.

It just occured to me, the location i specify for one projects javadoc, might be retained for a new EE project. I'll check and get back with my findings.

UPDATE: Sure enough, it would seem *the javadoc specified for one project persists for new ee projects too*. So we're good :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add Javadoc for any of the libraries that you are using in your Eclipse Projects.
Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path.

Now, on your Libraries tab, expand the jar that you are using(look for the Java EE jar). Expand it and you should see 4 sections (Source, Javadoc, Native Library, Access Rules). Click on Javadoc then you can edit (or just double-click Javadoc) and a dialog is brought up. 
Not navigate to the locations of the javadoc. It should contain a index.html in the root. Also you can validate it before clicking ok.
Now that you linked the javadoc directory, click ok.

That should work

Comment: Well, I'm using JBoss7.1 and I dont have a single JavaEE.jar. Jboss7 has several jar archives in different directories. I couldn't find any JavaDoc for it. I hoped I could tell Eclipse where it would find the JavaEE javadoc and automatically link it to the classes.